# Java CDI select alternative without priority

Tags: java, cdi, weld, deltaspike

I'm trying to replace a default implementation provided by DeltaSpike ([`LocaleResolver`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.9.3/)) with my own implementation via `@Alternative`.

```java
@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class ExampleLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {

}
```

```xml
<alternatives>
  <class>org.example.app.ExampleLocaleResolver</class>
</alternatives>
```

It seems the only way to make `ExampleLocaleResolver` the selected bean is by using `@Priority` or `@Specializes`.

For example, the following two works perfectly fine:

```java
@Priority(1)
@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class MyLocaleResolver implements LocaleResolver {

}
```

```java
@Specializes
@RequestScoped
public class MyLocaleResolver extends DefaultLocaleResolver {

}
```

My understanding is that with CDI 1.1+, it should be possible to override beans from libraries with alternatives without any kind of hacks.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm unable to inject the `@Alternative` bean without the `@Priorty` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Warning: I'm weak in the `@Alternative` area, but I think I understand this and can answer it accurately.)

I think the problem is that without using `@Priority` you are restricted to making assertions about bean archives, and your bean archive is not the same as the bean archive from which the DeltaSpike `LocaleResolver` is sourced.  My understanding is [in CDI 1.1+ the only way to cause *application-wide* `@Alternative` selection to happen is with the `@Priority` annotation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#declaring_selected_alternatives).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation and the docs cleared things up. I knew CDI 1.1 allowed global alternatives, I just didn't know Priority was needed to enable that functionality.